# Attempted to execute onEdit, but could not saved - Unexpected Identifier line 1

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to create a script to copy cells from one sheet to another.
When I used the debugger to check the code is correct until now it shows me an error in line 1.

I cannot understand where is the problem here,
[You can view the script here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W3tpp.png)
Appreciate your help upfront.

Comment: The word `function` should be in lower case. But I see no `onEdit()` function out there at all.

Comment: And you need to paste the code in your question as a text, not as an image.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow please take this opportunity to take the [tour] and learn how to [ask], [format code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks), [mcve] and [Learn More](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info)

Comment: I had a similar error message which went away after I put in function myFunction() which called my actual function.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write 'F' in lower case('f')